# How to send blob data through xmlhttprequest in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a blob data through `Xhr`. But i am not getting the blob data in the controller

I have written the code like:

```
var url = "Home/Content"
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
var blob = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'}); 
oReq.send("data="+blob);
```

In the controller i have defined like:

```
public ActionResult Content(string data)
{
  return Json("suc", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But the `data` i am retrieving is null. What i am doing wrong.

Comment: Actionresult => JsonResult ?

Comment: @codebrain I am using ActionResult

Answer (score 0):

I`ve solved this problem . 
You are sending binary data to mvc controller method and in that method you are getting the binary values as string take note this is the main cause of problem if you want to use save approach you should use

```
var fileContent = window.btoa(blob);

oReq.send(JSON.stringify({data: fileContent}));
```

so in your server side method

```
byte[] fileByte = Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side change

```
oReq.send("data="+blob);
```

to

```
oReq.send(blob);
```

Serverside/controller

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var r = Request;
    byte[] ba = r.BinaryRead(r.ContentLength);
   ...
 }
```

JavaScript can transfer binary data. see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data).

Basically binary data is sent & received without a name/variable.