# How to fetch audio file from blob URL in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, web-applications, blob

I have created a blob of audio obtained from a microphone in the browser and send this blob URL to Controller.

How should I fetch the audio file from blob URL in C#?

Comment: You should provide a lot more information on what you're doing, including some code. A "blob URL" could be lots of different things.

Comment: i am taking audio input from microphone using browser  (using javascript and got a blob URL like : blob:http://localhost:52971/f9b11071-5c04-4d8a-93ac-ee4271fce485) and need to process this audio .

Comment: The MVC controller can't access the blob URL in the browser. You'll need to post the blob to a controller action. Make an AJAX request using `FormData` or a JSON object.

Comment: can you provide some more details?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783302/sending-audio-blob-to-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454765/how-to-send-blob-data-through-xmlhttprequest-in-asp-net-mvc Problem Solved